# Symfony No route found

Tags: php, symfony-3.3

I want to make a new page, so I created a new bundle to create a new route to another page but there is a issue with routes 'No route found for "GET/products" '

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\ProductBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;




class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/products")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('ProductBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
}
```

this is my route

```
product:
resource: '@ProductBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation
```

The route appear when I execute the command `php bin/console debug:router` like this :

> product                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /products

I execute the command server: start and then server:run that the probleme still not fixed

can any one help me please

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? You can manually remove the cache folder or execute from the terminal the command `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Yes I did and nothing changed